# Very simple prop mapping not passing variable through correctly

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to React and actually cannot solve this very simple problem. I just want to pass the 'reviews' variable (declared from `const reviews = Reviews`) into the `AllReviews` component and output each review to the page.

However, I am seeing this error in my app:

Error in AllReviews.js (4:12)
';' expected.

I have a couple of questions:

1. When passing the reviews prop (i.e. `<AllReviews reviews=reviews />`), is this correct, or should it have this syntax: `<AllReviews reviews={reviews} />`? I tried both and assume it's the latter
2. What is the 4:12 stating?
3. And where should the ';' go? I do not know why it's erroring and why all the reviews are not showing

StackBlitz Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mbyhhe?file=AllReviews.js

Or see below - the index:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReviewsLeftArea from "./ReviewsLeftArea";
import ReviewsRightArea from "./ReviewsRightArea";
import AllReviews from "./AllReviews";
import "./style.css";
import "./fontawesome.min.css";
import Reviews from "./reviews.json";

const reviews = Reviews;

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="reviews-area-inner">
        <ReviewsLeftArea />
        <ReviewsRightArea />
        <AllReviews reviews={reviews} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("reviews-area-wrap"));
```

The reviews.json is in this format:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Joe Bloggs",
      "comment": "I liked it. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "rating": 4,
      "date": "22 April 2020",
      "init": true,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Bob Stiller",
      "comment": "Great, thanks.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    }
]
```

The AllReviews Component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function AllReviews(props) {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="all-reviews">
        {props.reviews}.map(review => (
          <div>
            <span>
              <b>Name:</b> {review.name}
            </span>
            <span>
              <b>Comments:</b> {review.comment}
            </span>
            <span>
              <b>Rating:</b> {review.rating}
            </span>
          </div>
        ))
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any advice would be very helpful. Thanks for any help here

Comment: `{props.reviews}.map` -> `props.reviews.map`

Comment: I still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the render methos in a functional component. It must be like this:

```
import React from "react";

const AllReviews = (props) =>  (
      <div id="all-reviews">
        {
        props.reviews.map((review) => (
          <div>
            <span>
              <b>Name:</b> {review.name}
            </span>
            <span>
              <b>Comments:</b> {review.comment}
            </span>
            <span>
              <b>Rating:</b> {review.rating}
            </span>
          </div>
        ))
       }
      </div>
    );


export default AllReviews;
```

Comment: thank you - but why did you have to change const AllReviews = (props) =>  ( to get it to work? id have thought my function AllReviews(props) line would have worked?

Comment: I don't think is strictly necessary but I was working on your snippet so I was just trying things! function should do aswell.

Answer (score 1):

1: The correct syntax is:

```
<AllReviews reviews={reviews} />
```

2 and 3: Your AllReviews component is a functional component, there is no render function in a functional component. Remove the render() { } and just keep the return ( )